# Height and size of \sqrt exponent

Tags: sqrt

I want to place the n from the `\sqrt[n]{\rho}` command in a more visible position and make it bigger too.

[image]

MWE:

```
\sqrt[n]{\rho}
```

Comment: can you ask that original to be more descriptive on his question title? That sloppy title could mean a bunch of things, hence why it was not recommended when I was typing the title for this duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package `amsmath` defines the `\leftroot` and `\uproot` commands to adjust the position of *n*. By default the size is `\scriptscriptstyle`. Compare different codes for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}


\[ \sqrt[n]{\rho}\quad \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{1}n]{\rho}\quad \sqrt[\leftroot{-1}\uproot{1}\scriptstyle n]{\rho} \]%

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: i thank you. i had to use -2 and 2 for this font

Answer (score 1):

The `amsmath` package provides the commands `\uproot` and `\leftroot` to modify the placemet of the root index.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\sqrt[\rho]{n}\ \sqrt[\uproot{2}\leftroot{2}\rho]{n}\ \sqrt[\uproot{2}\leftroot{-1}\rho]{n}$
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you really prefer ρ-th roots? ;o)

Comment: @Bernard - Moving `\rho` around seemed a lot more exciting...

Comment: An erhoctile ρ, so to say?

Comment: @Bernard - No comment... :-)